# what's the meaning of the circle node in pdgs which is generated by frama-c

Tags: c, static-analysis, frama-c

I use frama-c tool to analyse the code below.

```
  int main (int argc, char *argv[])
  {
     int i,a;
     for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 1)
     {
        a=0;
        if (a==0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
     }
     return 0;
  }
```

the cmd is

```
   frama-c -pdg -dot-pdg graph main.c
```

[image: 11]

My question is about the control dependence. what's the circle node means? I try to explain the "while" node, maybe it stand for one time loop , because a loop start from "i<100",so there a control dependence ("i<100" ------o "while" ). Is what I guess right ? but what is the "break" node mean? I guess that node "goto __Cont;" is related to the "break;" statement  in the "else" block. 
  I think I have no clear abstract model in my head for understanding the control dependence completely and accurately . Would you help me or give me any suggestion ?. Many Thanks in Advance Tao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command `frama-c -print main.c` to see how the program was translated (I include the translated version below).

The statement `goto __Cont;` in the normalized version is the translation of `continue;` in the original.

And, as Binyamin said, the `for` loop was normalized into a `while` loop.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int __retres;
  int i;
  int a;
  i = 0;
  while (i < 100) {
    a = 0;
    if (a == 0) { goto __Cont; }
    else { break; }
    __Cont: /* internal */ i ++;
  }
  __retres = 0;
  return (__retres);
}
```

Comment: Why "a=0" and "a==0" have a control dependence to circle"break"? because break will make them not execute any more?

Answer (score 1):

Most of it is self explanatory:

- circle - flow control (branching)
- rhombus - condition (`a == 0` etc.)
- square - assignment

Your for loop was translated to a while loop