# the meaning of kinds of curve in PDG

Tags: context-free-grammar, frama-c

I want know what's the meaning of a curve or arc in PDG.
Which are data dependence and which are control dependence and so on.

> [image]

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926688/whats-the-meaning-of-the-circle-node-in-pdgs-which-is-generated-by-frama-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926688/whats-the-meaning-of-the-circle-node-in-pdgs-which-is-generated-by-frama-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color of the edge represent the **data** dependencies : blue for yes, black otherwise.
The shape of the arrow represent the **control** dependencies : circle for yes, normal arrow otherwise. The kind of the line represent the **address** dependencies : dotted for yes, plain otherwise.

Address dependencies are like data dependencies, but for the right part of an assignment. For instance, the statement :

```
*p = c ? a : b;
```

has a control dependency on `c`, data dependencies on `a` and `b`, and address dependencies on `&p` and `p`.

Well, this is not exactly like this in the real PDG since the statement is decomposed by Frama-C in :

```
if (c) { *p = a; } else { *p = b; }
```

But this is the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much ,That's just what I wanted to know.